# Login manual laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Llevo varios días intentando autenticar de forma manual en laravel 5.8 con mi propia tabla de usuario de la base de datos que estoy usando y no la tabla users por defecto que trae laravel, para autenticar al usuario uso el rut del usuario y la password y el rut es una primary key de otra tabla(voluntarios), el problema es que no me autentica al usuario y los datos son correctos y siempre falla la autenticación(login fallido).

**A continuación dejo mi código, por favor necesito ayuda ya que es el proyecto de mi tesis**

**Login Controller**

```
class LoginController extends Controller {

    use AuthenticatesUsers;




    public function authenticate(Request $request) {

        $rut = $request->input('rut');
        $password = $request->input('password');



        if (Auth::attempt(['rut' => $rut, 'password' => $password])) {
           return view('usuario.menu');
        }else{
            echo 'login fallido';
        }
```

**Modelo Usuario**

```
class Usuario extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract
{

    use Authenticatable;



    protected $table = 'usuario';

    protected $fillable = [
        'rut', 'password'
    ];



      protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];




   }
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/login', 'UsuarioController@iniciar')->name('login');

Route::post('/loginprocess', 'Auth\LoginController@authenticate')->name('logueo');
```

Comment: Tu entidad de usuario si tiene id?, ¿Qué error te muestra? ¿Cuándo creas usuario encriptas la contraseña con Hash?

Prueba realizar esto: $usuario = Auth::attempt(['rut' => $rut, 'password' => $password]); dd($usuario); die(); para ver si te está encontrando el usuario con que querés autenticar

Comment: @LudOsorio gracias por responder, la tabla usuario no tiene id, y la contraseña no esta encriptada, realice lo que dijiste y sale **false** esto quiere decir que no me encuentra el usuario que quiero autenticar, alguna solución?

Comment: Probá agregar un columna id en tu entidad, como primaria y autoincrementable o sino, definí en tu modelo cual es la llave primaria de tu entidad usuario, lo haces de esta manera, protected primaryKey = 'tuLlavePrimaria';

Comment: @LudOsorio Amigo, hice lo que me dijiste en la tabla de usuario le puse un id como primary key autoincrementable y la defini en el modelo usuario  protected primaryKey = 'id' y nada sigue saliendo false.

Comment: Auth::attempt encripta el password que le pasas como parámetro para compararlo con el que está en BD, si los passwords en BD no están encriptados, siempre te dará false. Tendrías que crear tu propio método, [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47058849/7498116) un ejemplo

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Gracias Amigo me funciono!!, ahora puedo autenticar al usuario y también pude mostrar el rut del usuario autenticado, te lo agradezco  mucho y también a los que se dieron el tiempo de responderme gracias a todos.

Comment: @LuisMontalban Genial! si te animas, escribe una respuesta de como lo resolviste, así le puede servir a otros. Dale una leída a https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer y [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Obvio que si amigo, encantado!!, ahora escribiré la respuesta de la solución para contribuir a esta gran comunidad y ayudar a la gente que pueda tener el mismo problema que tuve yo.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno finalmente gracias a la gente de stackoverflow pude solucionar el problema de la autenticación manual y los problemas que tenia con login, aquí publico como solucione el problema para que otra gente lo tenga de referencia si tiene el mismo problema que tuve.
En el `LoginController` tuve que realizar las siguientes modificaciones tuve que autenticar al usuario por su **id**.

```
class LoginController extends Controller {

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    // funcion para iniciar sesion
    public function authenticate(Request $request) {


        $usuario = Usuario::where('rut', $request->rut)
                ->where('password', $request->password)
                ->first();

        if ($usuario) {
            Auth::loginUsingId($usuario->id);



            return view('usuario.menu');
        } else {
            return redirect('login')->with('status', 'Datos Incorrectos!');
        }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

En esta Parte déjalo como está

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract{
use Authenticatable;
protected $table = 'usuario';
```

El `Fillable` no es la que busca, es para registro, lo que debes hacer es usar un buscador de ficheros `sublime text ctrl+F` la cual ubica el `email`, en todos los campos que ésta usa pones el atributo con la cual cambias, en este caso `rut`, puedes intentar lo mismo en la contraseña, como `password -> contrasena`, al ser de Framework ya todo esta configurado, pero podemos hacer que busque por otro campo.

En caso de caso de no mover el núcleo, puedes hacerlo con `$guest` pero el rollo es mayor, finalmente, esta de mas pero cambiar en la vista el `name="email"` a `name="rut"`